# Fragment with layout_height set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working with a NestedScrollView, containing several fragments. I would like each fragment to occupy the height they need, without having to hardcode each fragment's size. So ideally, I would like to set the layout_height of the fragment (or its container) to wrap_content, but this doesn't work. The fragment is instantiated but doesn't appear.

```
<me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:name="com.example.MyFragment1"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:name="com.example.MyFragment2"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:name="com.example.MyFragment3"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

It tried with both methods: declaring the Fragment in layout file; or having a FrameLayout as a container and adding the fragment from Activity with Fragment Manager, but none of them worked.